# angular/akita store nested update

Tags: typescript, state, angular-akita

```
export interface Address {
    id: string,
    formData: FormData,
    addressData: AddressData,
    documentsData: DocumentsData
}

export interface AddressData {
    professional: AddressProfessional;
}

export interface AddressProfissional {
    typeA: AddressTypeA[];
    typeB: AddressTypeB[];
}

export interface AddressTypeA {
   name: string;
   surname: string;
   address: string;
   city: string;
   country: string;
}
```

I can update the store, but not sure what is the best way to update nested state, for example if I want to update the addressData -> AddressTypeA and update only the object being send that is {name & surname}

```
functionUpdateStore(data  => {
     this.store.update(state => ({
        ...state,
        addressData: data,
     }))
});
```

payload being send to update the store:
name: string;
surname: string;

Currently the store is being updated but not in the nested property. What is the best way to update nested object state?

Comment: Try to use `immer`, check this: https://datorama.github.io/akita/docs/immer